# ajaxError invoked on Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have set the ajax error handler in the client side

```
 $(document).ajaxError(processAjaxError);
 $.getJSON('/data.json');
```

In the server side

```
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.write('Hello, World!')
```

Even though i got 200 status code, still ajaxError callback is getting called since response data is not json. But in `processAjaxError` callback parameter, how do i get exact error message?

Comment: function processAjaxError ( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ){ ...here check for thrownError}

Comment: Thanks. I uses this parameter. Where do i see the exact error message.

Comment: @SSA I think this returns the HTTP status description, so wouldn't give the javascript error, as status code is 200 - OK"

Comment: Yes now I understand what he means.

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: @Fizer Khan, What do you get in thrownError ?

Answer (score 0):

The ajaxerror function should receive parameters in this order:

```
 event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/

Full example from the docs:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/missing.html" ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
    // Do whatever you want with thrownError here
  }
});
```

If you're trying to figure out *why* a 404 was thrown (if it was invalid json or some other reason), you could try parsing the responseText of the data you got back to rule out that possibility.

```
try {
    $.parseJSON(responseText);
} catch(err) {
    // Failed the json test
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the code i used. But the real problem is NOT with missing page(404) and other other http 400 or 500 status code. I got the response with 200 and but the response is not an valid json. Here the ajaxError callback does not have details of whether it is syntax error or something else

Comment: Added more to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But i really don't know, is the syntax error only possibility?